# Java BigDecimal can have comma instead dot?

Tags: java, decimal, bigdecimal

I have a string value that I want to assign to a BigDecimal. When I update the decimal value with a number like `100.23`, it works fine but when I update it with a number like `100,23` the code throws an exception. Why is that?

Comment: Please post your actual code and the "dump".

Comment: The javadocs of `BigDecimal` are pretty clear on what format is allowed; http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.lang.String)

Comment: BigDecimal doesn't have a dot or a comma.  You can parse a String which contains a comma and you can produce a string which contains a comma from a BigDecimal, but that doesn't mean the BigDecimal contains it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

because you tried to put a "," in a number.

you can use this code to parse a number with comma:

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE).parse("265,858")
```

you should also use float or double if there is no particular reason you use decimal.

Comment: "," is commonly used instead of "." in some parts of the world

Comment: @Zavior as i edited and gave an example. but still most common languages don't accept comma in a simple parse or assignment

Comment: You should not use float or double unless you're sure it's appropriate. Try System.out.println(new BigDecimal(100.23d)); - You can and sometimes will get off-by-one-cent rounding errors.

Comment: ...the particular reason being "you want to be sure about the value" :)

Comment: `BigDecimal` is designed to represent float numbers precisely. You should always use `BigDecimal` over double or float if you want to unambiguously represent a float number.

Answer (score 9):

If you can't be sure if your String has commas or points, you can use `replace(char, char)` from the String class. For example `myString.replace(',', '.')`.

Comment: That won't work if your String has BOTH commas and points, and you don't know which one is the grouping character and which one is the decimal separator.

Comment: Right, in this solution you have to know which symbol is used as decimal separator.

Answer (score 5):

The `BigDecimal(String)` constructor [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) lists all valid formats and characters.  Notice that the `,` is not included within this list.