# How to cast from String to BigDecimal with the separator as a comma?

Tags: java, numbers, number-formatting

I have a method to set a BigDecimal number that is given as String:

```java
private Client mapClient(Client client){
   ClientRequest clientRequest = new ClientRequest();
   // Code
   clientRequest.setCashAmount(castStringToBigDecimal(client.getCashAmount()));
   // More Code
}
```

My `castStringToBigDecimal` method is the follosing:

```
public BigDecimal castStringToBigDecimal(String value){
   BigDecimal response = null;
      if(value != null && !value.equals("")){
          value = value.replaceAll("[.]", ",");
          response = new BigDecimal(value);
      }

  return response;
}
```

An example of the input value is "1554.21"

I need that the bigDecimal separator to be a comma, not a dot. But this is giving me an exception.

**EDIT**

The value is the following:
[image]

And the exception is:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Character , is neither a decimal digit number, decimal point, nor "e" notation exponential mark.
```

Comment: Include the full trace of that exception in your paste, as well as the value you are passing to your `castStringToBigDecimal` method that is causing it.

Comment: Separately - that is not what cast means (cast is not the same as 'convert'), and generally you should be using `long`, not BigDecimal, for finance stuff.

Comment: I have edited the question to give you the info.

Comment: I'd be interested to know in what locale a decimal point is a comma?

Comment: @g00se In German locales for example.

Comment: @g00se I'm from Spain, and here we use the comma as decimal point.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714360/java-bigdecimal-can-have-comma-instead-dot

Comment: Ah it seems quite a few. But the point is, *only strings have formats*. `BigDecimal`'s string ctor won't accept locale variants, so the `BigDecimal` would have to be *formatted* as a string to have a comma as its separator, that is to say as the separator of its "FractionPart"

Comment: @Oles Onyshchak that gives me a number without decimals: 1554

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigDecimal doesn't represent a rendering. In other words, whether to use a comma or a dot as separator is not part of the properties a BigDecimal object has.

Hence, you do *not* want to call `.replaceAll`. (And separately, you'd want `.replace(".", ",")` - replace replaces all, and replaceAll also replaces all and interprets the first arg as a regex, and is therefore needlessly confusing here). Just pass it with the dot.

To *render* a BigDecimal, don't just sysout it, that will **always** show a dot and there is nothing you can do about that. `toString()` is almost never the appropriate tool for the job of rendering data to a user - it's a debugging aid, nothing more. Use e.g. `String.format("%f")`, specifying the appropriate locale. Or use [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html). The javadoc of BigDecimal explicitly spells this out.

There are various other issues with your code:

- "cast" is the technical name for the syntactic construct: `(Type) expr;` - and this construct does 3 utterly different things, hence using it to describe a task, i.e. use it in a method name, is a very bad idea. In particular, only one of the 3 things it does converts anything, and you clearly use it here in the 'convert something' meaning. This is misleading; only if it's all primitives does the cast operator convert, and BigDecimal isn't primitive. Call it `convertTo` or whatever you please, not "cast".
- BigDecimal is an extremely complicated tool for the job and usually not the right tool if you want to represent financial data. Instead, represent the atomary unit in a `long` and call the appropriate rendering method whenever you need to show it to a user. For example, for euros, the atomary unit is the eurocent. If something costs €1,50, you'd store "150", in a long. Before you think: But, wait, I want to divide, and then I'd lose half a cent! - yes, well, you can't exactly send your bank a request to transfer half a cent, either. Also, try to divide 4 cents by 3 with a BigDecimal and see what happens. Dividing financial amounts is tricky no matter what you use, BD isn't a catch-all solution to this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I looked up the source code for Java 8's implementation of BigDecimal (https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/math/BigDecimal.java), and the period character is hard-coded in that source as the decimal point. I would not have thought this of a language for which internationalization has been so thoroughly designed in, but there it is, line 466.

Given that the author(s) of BigDecimal failed to take locale into account in such a basic way -- the use of comma instead of period as the decimal separator in Europe is well-known -- I'd have to say you cannot use that BigDecimal constructor on unaltered Strings that are otherwise formatted correctly but which (might) have a comma separator. There are other options -- the previous SO post referred to in one of the comments has one -- but it appears you cannot convert your String this way.

(One minor point -- you are not "casting" anything. That word has a specific meaning in OO programming, and a more specific one in Java, and has very little to do with your question. It is incorrect to refer to conversion as casting.)

Comment: They have "failed to take locale into account" because that is supposed to be handled through a `DecimalFormat` instance (with `parseBigDecimal` set to true for parsing).

Comment: If that was the *reason* for failing to take locale into account, then BigDecimal should either have had no constructor with a String parameter that supposedly did a conversion, or at the very least should have mentioned it in JavaDoc. I don't know the order in which BigDecimal and DecimalFormat were written, and perhaps it is mentioned in Javadoc for a later version of Java. I'm still surprised that such a locale-dependent constructor was written for BigDecimal, ever.

Comment: The reason it has a string argument constructor is for easy of use to create values with an equivalent syntax as is supported for (double) literals (which also only allow a `.` as decimal separator). As can be seen in  the Javadoc, both BigDecimal and DecimalFormat were introduced in Java 1.1.